# BadFileException on Reading step of gcloud app deploy a python Flask application

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

When I use the command `gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug` I have the following outputs:

> DEBUG: Running [gcloud.app.deploy] with arguments: [--verbosity:
>   "debug"]
>
> DEBUG: Loading runtimes experiment config from
>   [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml] INFO: Reading
>   []
>
> DEBUG:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/macdowell/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/runtime_builders.py",
>   line 269, in _Read
>       with contextlib.closing(storage_client.ReadObject(object_)) as f:   File
>   "/home/macdowell/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/storage/storage_api.py",
>   line 302, in ReadObject
>       object_=object_ref, err=http_exc.HttpException(err)))
>   **BadFileException**: Could not read []. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object:
>   runtime-builders/experiments.yaml
>
> DEBUG: Experiment config file could not be read. Unable to read the
>   runtimes experiment config: [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml],
>   error: Could not read
>   []. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object:
>   runtime-builders/experiments.yaml
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/macdowell/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py",
>   line 126, in _ServerSideExperimentEnabled
>       runtimes_builder_root)
>   File "/home/macdowell/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/runtime_builders.py",
>   line 524, in LoadFromURI
>       .format(uri, e))
>
> ExperimentsError: Unable to read the runtimes experiment config:
>   [gs://runtime-builders/experiments.yaml], error: Could not read
>   []. Please retry: HTTPError 404: No such object:
>   runtime-builders/experiments.yaml
>
> DEBUG: API endpoint:
>   [https://appengine.googleapis.com/], API version: [v1

Here is the content of my ***app.yaml*** file:

```
runtime: python37
```

Comment: include your deployment files (app.yaml).

Comment: @JohnHanley the app.yaml file is already in the root dir. With configuration `runtime: python37`

Comment: @França Mac Dowell, please add your app.yaml file to your question so we can check your configuration

Comment: alright @KevinQuinzel, did it

Comment: It looks like this is a bug that has been reported here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145765092, please feel free to click "+1" on that issue to indicate that you are affected as well.

Comment: Your app.yaml is also effectively empty, try adding at least one [valid handler](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#handlers_element) to it.

Comment: Are you using GAE flexible or standard?

Comment: @DanCornilescu also tried

Comment: @NibrassHaider Standard!

Comment: do you give have the right permissions in order to create an App Engine Standard app? You can look into this [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/roles) to see whether you have a right role. You have to give yourself owner role to deploy.

Comment: Are you the owner of the project?

Comment: Yes @NibrassHaider, I'm as the Owner

Comment: What SDK version are you using?

Comment: Even if you have access to App Engine, in order to use the `gcloud command`, you need the [Storage Admin and Cloud Build Editor roles.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/roles#predefined_roles). If this isn't working for you, could you upload the error you encountered in the console? Also from your "Activity" tab, can you confirm that you are deploying your app with the right account?

Comment: França, did you manage to solve your problem? Same happening here, already tried all the suggestions (upgrade gcloud sdk, check permissions and billing...)

Comment: Ok, apparently, in my case, this "error" was not blocking, the build was just longer than usual (probably due to the new pip dependency resolver)